# How can I use that code about geosearch with React?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have that little code :

```
import {
  OpenStreetMapProvider,
} from 'leaflet-geosearch';

const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = form.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  provider.search({ query: input.value }).then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

I tried that :

```
import {
  OpenStreetMapProvider,
} from 'leaflet-geosearch';

const GeoSearchExample = () => {

const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

const form = document.querySelector('form');
const input = form.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  provider.search({ query: input.value }).then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
  });
});
return ()
}
```

But I don't know how to continue and `document.querySelector('form');` is not compatible with react like `form.addEventListener`

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: Why are you mixing vanilla js with react code.?